# Php button call php program

Tags: php, ajax, button

I am totally new. So this might seem basic. But I tried various methods and had no good results.

I am trying to build a browser based remote control to my sonos. I have various php programs to play, volume up, etc

How do I display multiple buttons that when pressed calls up the related php programs to control the sonos. Ideally the displayed page should stay at the same page showing the buttons.

Please guide me on the php/html code

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with php programs? Does your sonos have API?

Comment: https://github.com/DjMomo/sonos/blob/master/ why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @veeenex. SONOS does not have official Apis but people have figure it out using Post over the network. Just as Daryl Gill have suggested

Comment: @DarylGill yes. This is exactly what I am using. I figured out the php code. But now I want to build the web interface hence I am trying figure out the buttons to call up the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i followed this example

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

on this line " xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true); "

i changed out the *.txt for my *.php program that i am calling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
In HTML add button with identifier, for exp. id="run", then use AJAX in JQuery library to make a request to your server if someone hit the button with id run and this is how you can execute yours php codes in one page.
And try to learn basics as reading files,printing texts, about OOP and so on.

Comment: thanks for your patience. When I try this for example, http://jsfiddle.net/R77EB/. Couple problems, when I substitute my php code into the function call, it seems to run the function before the button is pressed. So I am having trouble apparently on figuring out the conditional..  Also I want the page not redirect to a different page but remain on the same page so that I can press another button, ideally the button color should change color or something to verify the button ip and function is initiated. Thanks again

Comment: @user1117057 I think you have a problem with default event of that button, then you should use `e.preventDefault` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: thanks, but I have a hard time understanding this code.  can you help me in editing the program to use a graphics button and calling up a php program on click?  Sorry I tried to paste the example code here, but can't get it to show correctly

Comment: @user1117057 can you be more obvious What do you understand as program?